# Determining if shapefile and raster overlap in Python using OGR/GDAL?

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, gdal, ogr

I am building a script in python using OGR/GDAL.

I have a set of shapefiles and a set of GeoTiff raster files.

I would like to have my script ignore shapefiles if they do not intersect with the raster area.

The shapefile is not a rectangle, so I cannot simply compare the xmin/xmax,ymin/ymax values returned by layer.GetExtent(). I need the actual polygon representing it's overall shape, and then some way of determining if that polygon intersects with the raster square.

I was thinking I could somehow merge all the polygons in the shapefile into one feature, and then read the geometry on that feature, and then compare that information to the raster extent. However, I am unsure of specifically how to execute this.

1. How to extract border polygon information from shapefile?
2. How to determine if that polygon intersects a given square area?

Comment: I'm not familiar with osgeo, but the arcpy equivalent would (might) involve: read raster extent, create polygon covering extent in memory, cycle through shapefiles, clipping each to extent rectangle, test if anything results.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following script determines the bounding box of a raster and creates based on the bounding box a geometry.

```
import ogr, gdal

raster = gdal.Open('sample.tif')
vector = ogr.Open('sample.shp')

# Get raster geometry
transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]
cols = raster.RasterXSize
rows = raster.RasterYSize

xLeft = transform[0]
yTop = transform[3]
xRight = xLeft+cols*pixelWidth
yBottom = yTop-rows*pixelHeight

ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(xLeft, yTop)
ring.AddPoint(xLeft, yBottom)
ring.AddPoint(xRight, yTop)
ring.AddPoint(xRight, yBottom)
ring.AddPoint(xLeft, yTop)
rasterGeometry = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
rasterGeometry.AddGeometry(ring)
```

Next, the geometry of the vector polygon is determined. This answers your first question.

```
# Get vector geometry
layer = vector.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
vectorGeometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
```

Last, the geometry of the vector and raster are tested for intersection (returns `True` or `False`). This answers your second question.

```
print rasterGeometry.Intersect(vectorGeometry)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. This answer clearly shows how to create, extract, and run functions between geometry objects, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This solution test whether the FID = 0 polygon intersects with the raster. How do you get the geometry of the shapefile total when no polygon represents this?

Comment: EDIT: The increase in computation time is inconsequential so I check if each polygon in the shapefile intersects now.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful solution, however  pixelHeight seems to be negative when the zone is in the Southern hemisphere (we should check the behavior of raster.GetGeoTransform()). `yBottom = yTop-abs(rows*pixelHeight)` fixes this.

Answer (score 6):

I find @ustroetz solution very helpful but it needed to be corrected in two places.
Firstly, pixelHeight = transform[5] is already negative value, so equation should be

```
yBottom = yTop+rows*pixelHeight
```

Secondly, the order of the points in the ring must be 
counter clockwise. I was having problems with that. Correct order is:

```
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(xLeft, yTop)
ring.AddPoint(xLeft, yBottom)
ring.AddPoint(xRight, yBottom)
ring.AddPoint(xRight, yTop)
ring.AddPoint(xLeft, yTop)
```